How should I connect a light fixture with UK wire colors to US wiring?
I'm installing a chandelier light in the US; it's just on-off, not a 3-way.  The light comes with an LED bulb, and the wires are 16 gauge.  But what has me puzzled is that the two wires (the ground is separate) appear to be blue and brown.  Which connects to the white and which to the black in our house wiring?  (The instructions are useless.)
I checked how the wires connect to the light bulb socket: the brown wire is the socket's center post (hot contact), the blue is the socket's collar (neutral).  So I assume the brown wire on the fixture should go to the black wire in the house, and the blue wire to the white.  Correct?



Wrong Colors

That indicates either designed for the UK or some other place outside US/Canada or cheap junk from a very large Asian country. Designed for UK is actually OK if designed and manufactured properly, as plenty of LED lighting can handle a full voltage range from 100V to 250V.

The instructions are useless

That confirms that it is cheap junk from a very large Asian country.
Do NOT install any hardwired electrical items (lighting, switches, receptacles, timers, fans, etc.) unless it is marked with an appropriate safety mark or you have other evidence (e.g., custom-made by a local reputable company using quality parts)  that it is safe. In the US that usually means UL or ETL listing. I think it is a pretty safe bet that the markings on this item do not include UL or ETL. They might include other marks such as:

CE - Has some meaning in some places, but not in the US
TM - Trademark - nothing to do with safety
FCC - Radio frequency issues - can be important but doesn't guarantee safety (assuming it is legitimate)

and there are probably quite a few others. UL and ETL are what matter in the US, and while those could be faked, for legal reasons they generally are not. A mark such as TUV indicating proper certification in another country may be sufficient and is, at a minimum, an indication of a quality design/manufacture. But without such certification, the risk of installing a hardwired device is not worth the savings.

Well, some products are merely global rather than junque, but likely this is junque. Cutting an IEC cord from an old Mac will reveal yellow striped green, blue and brown per rest of the planet standards and it definitely got tested for sale here (not that they'd expect you to be cutting the cord as a proper end-user...but once I've junked the computer and I have more IEC cords than I need, if I need a decent-quality power cord I'm not averse.)

@Ecnerwal Agreed. Wrong colors don't mean something is bad. But if that is combined with useless instructions and lack of required safety indications then...

I should clarify what I mean when I say that the instructions are useless: I think we got half the instructions.  There is one instruction page, drawings without text, and it starts at step 3.  Missing entirely is the part where you wire it up.  It's possible that the missing instructions would explain the wiring--or not :).

As for the marks, it has CE; no UL or ETL.

Afaik loose strands (without crimp sleeve) are not legal in Europe.

@MikeMaxwell for CE mark, make sure it's the 'right' one; look up 'China Export' and 'Conformité Européene'; the labels are very similar. Although they both have no value in the US, one is somewhat more trustworthy than the other.

@Agent_L not sure about that but unstripped wires are quite commonly found and we don't know if the OP stripped them

@Agent_L Non-crimped loose strands are definitely legal, and normal, in the UK. It is up to the installer to twist the strands together before inserting into the fitting and to make sure no loose strands are poking out.

@Excellor Note that the caption on that image contains the word "alleged", and its use is in a section of the Wikipedia article about how this is an urban myth. In other words, there may be outright fraudulent use of the mark, but there is no legitimate "China Export" mark.

@MikeMaxwell - Often if you got instructions, you can go to the manufacturer's website, look up the item you have, and download a copy of the instructions. That could get you the oddly missing page.

@Chris H: I did indeed strip the wires myself.  They came unstripped.

Actually TÜV is a listed NRTL in the US, here is a full list: https://www.osha.gov/nationally-recognized-testing-laboratory-program/current-list-of-nrtls

the red wire is the socket's center post (hot contact), the blue is the socket's collar (neutral)
It is the rule to connect the hot to the center and the neural to the outside of the bulb socket to prevent you from been electrocuted when changing the bulb with power on.
tells you all you need.
The Red is to connect with black
and the blue is to connect with white
The CE marking is mainly used in Europe
It is a Mandatory conformity marking for products sold in the European Economic Area

But '(The instructions are useless.)' is a very strong clue that it's junk, since the instructions are part of a product getting listed. And if it's not listed, it may have serious flaws that are not obvious to casual inspection, such as wire & cable insulation that burns really well rather than being fire retardant, for instance.

@Ecnerwal from OP I should clarify what I mean when I say that the instructions are useless: I think we got half the instructions. There is one instruction page, drawings without text, and it starts at step 3. Missing entirely is the part where you wire it up. It's possible that the missing instructions would explain the wiring--or not :)

The OP has also reported that it has only a CE mark, which is not a nationally recognized testing laboratory mark (at all, anywhere on the planet.) It's an "affirmation" by the manufacturer that a product meets EU rules, and what little meaning it might have vanishes if the product is not being sent to the EU, since it's never going to face enforcement of any kind. A legit electrical product going into the EU would likely have a TUV or other regional test lab marking in addition to the CE - just as legit products for North Americal get UL, ETL or CSA marks (and often have a CE mark, too.)

In European locales brown = hot and blue = neutral. It may very well be that the manufacturer makes this device for multiple markets, and didn't bother to 'internationalize' it for North American markets which use black / white for hot and neutral.
Does it mean the fixture is unsafe? Hard to say. If it doesn't have a real UL and or CSA mark, I'd not use it.
What if it has a 'CE' mark? Well, that's problematic too. CE marking is a self-certification that, while it’s supposed to be backed up with documentation, is mostly based on an honor system with its Declaration of Conformity submitted with the importation paperwork. More about this here, from TüV Rheinland: https://insights.tuv.com/blog/why-manufacturers-lie-about-ce-marking
Taken together, a fixture lacking appropriate North American certification, plus the wrong wiring colors speaks of a supplier lacking in attention to detail, casting doubt on the fixture’s quality and safety.

The biggest worry I'd have with it being an appearing to be EU designed item in the US is if it will work on only 120V or if someone saved a few pennies by making a 240V only design.  While not dangerous in the way that running a 120V only device at 240V is, that doesn't mean it will work either.

The "China Export" thing is an urban legend. Which is not to say that fake CE marks don't exist.

Apropos of the urban legend question:, here's an EU statement saying they're not aware of any "China Export" use of the symbol: https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/P-6-2007-5938-ASW_EN.html.  That's dated 2008, unclear whether the situation has changed since then.

It is likely that the EU politicos soft-pedaled the ‘China Export’ issue to avoid a trade dustup with China. I added content from TüV about the problem of fake CE marking.
